# Neo4J: Querying a node index (with wildcards) via the webadmin Data Browser

Tags: neo4j

Using a default index, one can do `nodeIndex.get("message", "Hello")` for exact matches, or `nodeIndex.query("message", "Hel*")` for approximate Lucene-based queries. This works correctly for me from Java.

But how do I do approximate queries through the webadmin Data Browser interface? Exact matches work fine, such as:

```
node:index:nodeIndex:message:"Hello"
```

but I can't see how to do the wildcard queries. The syntax is shown in the pop-up help panel as:

```
node:index:[index]:[query]
```

but I don't know what to put for the `[query]` part, and can't find any examples of this in the [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/index.html) or the [wiki](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Main_Page). Have tried the following without success:

```
node:index:nodeIndex:"message:Hel*"
node:index:nodeIndex:message:"Hel*"
node:index:nodeIndex:"Hel*"
node:index:nodeIndex:Hel*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
node:index:nodeIndex:message:Hel*
```

The `query`is message:Hel* so you just append it, more complex queries are also possible.
See the [lucene syntax guide](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/queryparsersyntax.html).

```
node:index:nodeIndex:message:Hel* OR message:Wor*
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you! Would be good if this kind of simple example could be added to the documentation on querying and/or the documentation on the Data Browser interface.

Comment: I'm using ver1.8 right now, this doesn't work, did it change ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue created. https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/138

Comment: I have added a few initial notes to the wiki page at http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Webadmin ...